# Windows file to look for to test LFI

Tags: windows, directory-traversal

For Linux, if we want to test local file inclusion we always search for `/etc/passwd`

For old versions of Windows,  (e.g. Windows XP) we search for `win.ini`

What file should I search for in later versions of Windows that is readable and always there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` is pretty commonly used to check for read access to the file system while pentesting. If I remember correctly, this file exists on Windows 7 and later, but I'm not sure if it exists on earlier versions.

Comment: pretty sure it's present since at least win xp

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the `hosts` file like @nobody's answer. FWIW I usually look at this too which includes some other files of interest for an LFI: https://gracefulsecurity.com/path-traversal-cheat-sheet-windows/.